# Prove/disprove this set of functions is equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to figure out whether the set of functions $$\{ g_a : a \in [1, \infty)\; in\; C[-1,1], \  g_{a}(x) = \frac {1}{(x-a)^{2}+1} \}$$ is equicontinuous.

I have tried to manipulate the inequality $|g_{a}(x) - g_{a}(y)|$ and i got that $|g_{a}(x) - g_{a}(y)| \le |y-x| |2a+2|$ but this doesn't really give me a value of $\delta$ that works for any $a$. I'm stuck. I also don't really have an intuition for whether it is equicontinuous or not.. is there anything that should hint this to me?

Comment: There is $M > 0$ such that $|g_a'| \leq M$ for all $a \geq 1$. This means all the functions share a Lispchitz constant, so they are equicontinuous.

Comment: @Mason ahh wow that makes things so much easier thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose an $\epsilon > 0$ and take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Let $|y-x|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then:
\begin{align}
|g_a(x)-g_a(y)|&=\Big|\frac{1}{(x-a)^2+1}-\frac{1}{(y-a)^2+1}\Big| \\
               &=\frac{|y-x|~|y+x-2a|}{[(x-a)^2+1]~[(y-a)^2+1]} \\
            & \leq \frac{|y-x|~(|y-a|+|x-a|)}{[(x-a)^2+1]~[(y-a)^2+1]} \\
           &=|y-x|~\Big[\frac{|x-a|}{[(x-a)^2+1]~[(y-a)^2+1]}+\frac{|y-a|}{[(x-a)^2+1]~[(y-a)^2+1]}\Big]
\end{align}
Now if $|x-a|<1$ then $(x-a)^2+1-|x-a|\geq0 \Rightarrow \frac{|x-a|}{[(x-a)^2+1]} \leq 1 \Rightarrow \frac{|x-a|}{[(x-a)^2+1]~[(y-a)^2+1]} \leq 1$.

If $|x-a|\geq 1$ then $|x-a| \leq (x-a)^2 \leq (x-a)^2 +1 \Rightarrow  \frac{|x-a|}{[(x-a)^2+1]} \leq 1 \Rightarrow \frac{|x-a|}{[(x-a)^2+1]~[(y-a)^2+1]} \leq 1$.

Thus in any case we have $ \frac{|x-a|}{[(x-a)^2+1]~[(y-a)^2+1]} \leq 1$. Similar for $y$ related exdpression.
Now from above we get
\begin{equation}
 |g_a(x)-g_a(y)| \leq 2~|y-x|<\epsilon
\end{equation}
for all $a$.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up!

Comment: You're welcome.